# closure and intersection of sets

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n.$ If $A\cap B\neq \emptyset,$ is it necessarily true that $\overline{A\cap B} = \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$? Prove or disprove. Is it true that if $A\cap B = \emptyset,$ then $int(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}) = \emptyset$?

This seems true, but I'm not sure how to prove it. For instance, if you take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = (0,1),$ it holds.
I know how to show that $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$ (and this works regardless of whether $A\cap B = \emptyset$). To show that $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\subseteq \overline{A\cap B},$ let $x \in \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}.$ Then $\exists (x_n)\subseteq A$ so that $x_n \to x$ and $\exists (y_n)\subseteq B$ so that $y_n\to x.$ Since $A\cap B\neq \emptyset,$ we may find $z \in A\cap B.$ We want to construct/show the existence of a sequence $(z_n)\subseteq A\cap B$ so that $z_n\to x.$

The second claim is false, I believe; take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}.$ Then $A\cap B = \emptyset,$ but $\overline{A} = \overline{B} = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Are you talking only about subsets of $\Bbb R$? Because in general topological spaces a point in $\operatorname{cl}A$ need not be the limit of a sequence in $A$.

Comment: I'm taking about in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary true that $\overline{A \cap B}=\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$.
For example: Take $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}^c$.
$$(\overline{\Bbb{Q}\cap\Bbb{Q}^c})=\varnothing$$ but $$\overline{\Bbb{Q}}\cap \overline{\Bbb{Q}^c}=\Bbb{R}\cap\Bbb{R}=\Bbb{R}.$$
This example also disproves your second claim.

Comment: @Gord452 Sorry, I don't know what does "Vol" mean. I am a  beginner in general topology.

Comment: What you have asked here. I can only help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am correct about my second claim. It seems the first claim is false, however; indeed taking $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}\cup \{0\}$ results in $\overline{A\cap B} = \{0\}\neq \overline{A}\cap \overline{B} = \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Note that your example also disproves the second claim.. Use the original $A$ is rationals, $B$ irrationals. It works for both.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't understand. That can't work for both as $A\cap B = \emptyset$, so it doesn't disprove the first proposition.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma would you mind taking a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772852/volume-of-disjoint-union)? The definition of volume I'm using is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768393/volume-of-bounded-sets-of-mathbbrn).

Comment: @Gord452. Sorry asking here, but I have no more contact: what happened with your question about "non differentiable function " seems it is differentiable, no? I have not pretensions, but my time, may be valued little.

Comment: @zkutch sry. I'll reopen it.